# Using IncludePackageName = false in AddServiceFabricConfiguration does not change setting in Service Fabric AspNetCore config?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to get rid of the "Config:" prefix added by `AddServiceFabricConfiguration` with AspNet Core to follow the same naming regardless of configuration source.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore#multiple-configuration-packages) you should set `IncludePackageName = false` which I do like this:

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder => {                           
  builder.AddServiceFabricConfiguration(serviceContext.CodePackageActivationContext, options => options.IncludePackageName = false);
})
```

But when I'm running the application the configuration is populated like this with `IncludePackageName` set to `true` anyway.

How can I make this setting work? The `ServiceFabricConfigurationProvider` which the helper adds is not public so I can't find a suitable workaround.

[image: Applied options]

Answer (score 0):

Update: This seems to have been some issue with my local environment rather than the actual code. Reboot, clean and rebuild fixed the issue.